# "Committed to build" vs. "committed to building"

Tags: grammaticality, verbs, infinitives, gerunds

If this were a mere tagline, not a complete sentence in a full paragraph, which would be more correct?

> 1. Committed to build a better world
> 2. Committed to building a better world

Comment: Your question is not quite clear. What aspect are you questioning? What is the alternative? (By the way, the phrase you offer is not a complete sentence.)

Comment: It's a tagline. That's why.

Comment: Because it's a tagline, it's not possible to say which is "more correct" without knowing what you intend it to mean. (2) is certainly more usual, probably because it is *present continuous* and indicates a current activity; (1) could be construed as not having started yet.

Comment: @Andrew, so "to building" is present continuous and "to build" future tense?

Comment: If the tagline were to be used as advertising for an architectural firm, I'd say number two is better.  If the firm is known for its award-winning green designs, for example, "Committed to building a better world" just has a better ring to it than "Committed to build a better world."  IMHO.

Comment: @AndrewLeach, this is the same explanation my grammar teacher gave me. Where to use infinitive and to+verb+ing has always confused me.

Answer (score 1):

The meanings are slightly different.
I understand it as

> 1. "Being" committed "in order to" build a better world.
> 2. Committed to "the task of" building a better world.

Of course, being a tagline, nobody really cares. The first impression meanings are about the same.